# Which serial killer is noted to have the most kills in movie & TV history?

Tags: most-appearances

After revisiting the seasons of *Dexter*, I asked myself, "How many individuals has he killed in all 8 seasons?" According to this [list](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Dexter's_Kill_List) he has an "impressive" kill count of 135.  After seeing this I wondered if there is an even more "productive" serial killer in movie and TV history.

A *[serial killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_killer)* as defined by Wikipedia:

> A serial killer is a person who murders three or more people, usually in service of abnormal psychological gratification, with the murders taking place over more than a month and including a significant break (a "cooling off period") between them.

So,  which serial killer has racked up the most kills over the course of their appearances in film and TV?

If possible please add a source that can confirms the number of killings.

Comment: Kevin Uxbridge killed fifty billion Husnock people in the show Star Trek The Next Generation.

Comment: @user3147268 _American Psycho_ Patrick Bateman Kill around 6 people .[American Psycho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Psycho_%28film%29).

Comment: @New-To-IT This is not a serial killer by definition. Genocide and mass killings are not serial murders. In fact, the OP might elaborate a bit more about serial killers before this turns into a 'character who killed the most people' question.

Comment: As a note, mentioning *Dexter* in the question doesn't make this about Dexter.

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration. BTW, you might want to look into the [many, many films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_B%C3%A1thory_in_popular_culture#Film) that featured Elizabeth Bathory, who's known as the worst female serial killer in history and was alleged to have killed over 600 girls.

Comment: @Walt nothing in the wiki, or real/fbi/DOJ definition of serial killer excludes genocide or mass killings. In fact, the real criminal definition is: `Protection of Children from Sexual Predator Act of 1998 (Title 18, United States Code, Chapter 51, and Section 1111). This law includes a definition of serial killings:

The term ‘serial killings’ means a series of three or more killings, not less than one of which was committed within the United States, having common characteristics such as to suggest the reasonable possibility that the crimes were committed by the same actor or actors.`

Comment: And the time thing is weirdly stated. The normal definition of serial killers doesn't include a *significant* break, or *cooling off period*. It's simply enough time to separate the killings, as opposed to a mass/spree killer. Kill 4 people over 4 days, serial killer ex: **the Beltway sniper.** Kill 4 people at the same school/day, spree killer, ex: **Virginia Tech**.

Comment: @cde Beltway sniper started killing people in February and was caught in October.

Comment: @Catija but the beltway attacks were over 3 weeks. `The Beltway sniper attacks were a series of coordinated shootings that took place over three weeks in October 2002 in Maryland, Virginia, and Washington, D.C. Ten people were killed and three other victims were critically injured in several locations`

Comment: @cde And? Being a serial killer isn't limited to only your most recent attacks. Some serial killers (in TV shows/films at least) kill one person every 5 years... that doesn't make them not a serial killer because they only have one recent killing. If the Beltway sniper had only killed people over the four days you originally mentioned, he may very well have been considered a spree killer and it was only the fact that the other killings exist that makes him a serial killer.

Comment: @Catija I said he's a serial killer. ???

Comment: Also, just because that definition doesn't exclude genocide, it's generally impossible for one person to be responsible for the entire genocide (short of pushing the button on the Death Star to wipe out an entire planet). Even then, I'm pretty sure no one would say that Vader was a serial killer since his organization did it at his direction. That definition is very reductive.

Comment: @cde When did I say you didn't? I'm clarifying because you stated he did his killings over four days as an explanation of the cooling off period statement in the Wiki quote being wrong. I'm explaining that the Beltway Sniper isn't a good argument against the definition

Comment: @Erik: I nominate James Bond.  He's got 2 dozen films now, and kills countless mooks in every one of them.  That's assuming you count all of the actors who have played him as being the same character, of course...

Comment: Oh dear, this is indeed threatening to turn into a generic 'most lethal character ever'... Soldiers, secret agents and just action heroes in general are *not*, AFAIK, serial killers.

Comment: @Erik The serial killer should be represented by the character, not different actors that played him.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, Daniel Craig definitely isn't the same Bond as the others (since they don't share a continuity, it was a reboot). Whether or not you consider all of the others as the same person is up for debate.

Answer (score 7):

[Jason Voorhees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Voorhees) the serial killer from series of [Friday The 13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_(franchise)) movies seems to fit the bill here. With a total of 12/13 villain movies stretching from 1981 to the present and having believed to have killed in excess of [300 victims](http://bloody-disgusting.com/news/3316822/10-deadliest-horror-movie-villains-kill-count/), he is the most successful serial killer of all, in the movies!

Comment: Was Voorhees really a serial killer?  A mass-murderer, no doubt, but serial killers kill in a specific fashion and/or target a specific demographic.  Voorhees' murders didn't really follow a pattern, except to say that *most* of his victims were teens or young adults.

Comment: As I understand it, to qualify as a serial killer he only *needs* to have killed more than 3 people in more than 1 incident that span at least a month. Having an MO is pretty typical for serial killers but not really mandatory.

Comment: Does this take into account that he wasn't in 2 of the movies?

Comment: @JohnnyBones promiscuous, drug/alcohol using, or otherwise immoral teens/young adults, and anyone who gets in his way (collateral damage). He doesn't kill indiscriminately. There are plenty people who see him and he doesn't even attempt to kill them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obtc9U6hEYM

Comment: Not really. The definition also includes aberrent psychological gratification and cooling off periods (extended) between victims. Probably an academic distinction as most descriptions say he is a serial.

Answer (score 4):

On the show Criminal Minds, the most prolific killer they encountered was [Frank Breitkopf](http://criminalminds.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Breitkopf) in S02E13 and S02E24. He had amassed **176 kills** by the time he was caught.

I would assume that he fits the description of a serial killer quite well by whichever definition used, as he kills victims of a specific demographic in a specific repeated manner with long time intervals between each one.